# Configuring WebDAV for folders with index.php

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, webdav

I'm trying to setup a remote server for webdevelopment purposes. We want to use WebDAV for connecting our Windows-systems with this Linux server, which is working great now - the server is attached as a network mount and browsing over the server works good.

But, I cannot open folders which contains files named index.php.

Why is this? How can I fix this?